# Python functions: Pass global variables if only accessing them?

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments, global

I'm trying to get a sense of best practices in python. If I define a function to access (but not change) a global variable, it's not generally necessary to specify the variable as global in the function. But is it faster to pass the global variable to the function? I ask because I've come across some references to the cost of looking up global variables, but I'm not sure that I understand. For example:

```
def f1(localList):
    for element in localList:
        if element in globalSet:
            pass #do stuff.

def f2(localList, localSet):
    for element in localList:
        if element in localSet:
            pass #do stuff.

globalList = <arbitrary list>
globalSet  = <arbitrary set>

f1(globalList)
f2(globalList, globalSet)
```

is f2 generally considered to be the faster/better/more "pythonic" approach compared to f1?

Comment: Could you share a real example of what are you trying to do? Choosing one approach over the other might be a design choice. (For sure a bad design would be using global, but you didn't use it in either case).

Comment: Actually I don't have any particular example at hand in this case. It's just that I've written a few scripts and it's been on my mind whether there is a general rule or convention about this. I like the way python lets me access globalSet transparently in f1, but if globalSet has to be looked up for each iteration of the loop in f1, then if globalList is large I guess f2 is preferable?

Comment: No it's to prefer for that reason, it should even really matter. It's a design choice depending on what you're actually building. In python there should be only obvious way for doing things, so your doubt might be a sign og bad design. Maybe you just need a class.

Comment: I haven't much explored class-based approaches in python beyond some simple struct-like stuff. Since you, Abhijit and KurzedMetal have all suggested it I will definitely look into it.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code. If you have doubts about your working code, you can ask for a review on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Using Globals is always a bad design choice. In any case you can always come up with a solution which would be more Pythonic by not using Globals.

- If you have to share lot of variables between functions, you can
  reconsider an OO approach.
- If you have to pass many parameter's to a
  functions, you can opt for varargs or kargs.

Remember, parameters are passed by reference so there is no efficiency lost.

*----Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.*

Answer (score 0):

If `globalList` and `globalSet` data is tightly bound to the functions i'd use a class and define those lists as class propierties and those functions as staticmethods (or instance methods, whatever i need)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are [generally considered bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) in programming in general. Basically because any code that can see the variable can change it. Especially in multithreaded programs this can be a source of bugs.

You should think of Python variables as names for, or references to objects. So passing a variable to a function isn't costly.