# Should I pass sympy symbols to functions?

Tags: python, global-variables, sympy

Is there any disadvantage of not passing sympy symbols to functions?

```
def compute(alpha,a): #or def compute(a)
    return 3*alpha+a

alpha = sympy.symbols("alpha")
expr = compute(alpha,3)
```

I don't have to pass `alpha` to `compute()` (I assume because it's a global variable), and right now, I think it makes the code better readable when I leave it out.
Is this considered bad design? I suppose this is a general "what to do with global variables in python" question, as has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234901/python-functions-pass-global-variables-if-only-accessing-them), but the answers said it would depend on the specific usecase.

I still have to create the `alpha` symbol before I call that function, it's just not obvious if i do not include it.

Comment: Unless there is some good reason not to, pass the variable as an argument into the function instead of having it read a global. It makes for clearer and more robust code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to lists (which the other question is about), [SymPy treats symbols (and expressions) as immutable](//docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/basic_operations.html). Moreover, they are uniquely identified by the string you pass to `Symbol` or `symbols`. For illustration consider the following:

```
from sympy import Symbol
print({Symbol("a"), Symbol("a")})
>>> {a}
```

Therefore declaring a SymPy symbol as a global variable does not pose such a big issue – it’s like globally defining some mathematical constant. For example it cannot happen that some reasonable code using this symbol changes it.¹

So, depending on the context, it can make sense to:

1. define `alpha` globally,
2. pass `alpha` as a parameter to the function,
3. define `alpha` within the function at each call (which is possible, since symbols only depend on the associated string).

Without further context, it’s impossible to say which applies to your situation.

---

¹ Note that unreasonable code can still do this, e.g.:

```
from sympy.abc import a
from sympy.abc import a as a_2
a.name = "b"
print(a_2)
>>> b
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining commonly used Symbols at the top of the file (i.e., globally) is perfectly good practice. As others have pointed out, even if it gets defined again, it won't really matter because two symbols with the same name are considered equal.  *One important caveat here: if you use assumptions, like `real=True`, then that does matter. So you should avoid using two symbols with the same name but different assumptions.*

In your example, if `alpha` is always supposed to be the symbol `Symbol('alpha')`, then it doesn't make sense to have an argument to a function that never changes.

---

Another way you can do things, by the way, is to not have the function at all, but just use the expression with symbolic variables

```
alpha, a = symbols('alpha a')
expr = 3*alpha + a
```

and then use subs when you want to substitute a value

```
expr.subs({a: 3}) # or expr.subs(a, 3)
```